# C# Render HTML to get element's height

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to create an HTML page from a C# code with HTML Agility Pack. 
What I want is that if the element I'm trying to write cannot fit into a div with a specific height, it must create a new div and close the other one (like a paging if you want). 
My big concern is how to know the height of my element inside C#, I assume I'm force to render it somewhere with the CSS associated, but how?

Comment: This would be a mighty task, not just because you'd have to calculate the overall box size on your own (e.g. read the attributes after `PreRender`) - but you'd also need to know what browser and what version because of the boxing model that exists on each browser.

Comment: Can you use javascript to store the value of the height of the element you want in a hidden element and look at the contents of that element from C#?

Comment: You could do it in javascript, and retrieve your elements via a webservice or something like that, it would be easier

Comment: Using JS mean that I was already able to render it, so what is the best way to render it. @neoistheone As you said it depend also from the browser used. I had in mind using either [Open WebKit](https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/) or [HTML Rederer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) or even the WinForm HTML Componment. I don't really know which one is the best considering that after generating the html I have to print it in pdf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using an HTML renderer like [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/).

You would then be able to call the javascript in it to retrieve DOM objects properties like heights, position, etc...

Once you have set and rendered the content you want to test ([tutorial here](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php)), use `StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` function to access javascript functions.

```
string height = webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("$('#divID').height().toString()");
```

Note that you need to return a string value as this function does not return other types.